# Pick A Character So That Every Character in the File Has Equal Probability of Being Chosen

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm reading a book called A Practical Guide to Quantitative Finance interview and got the following question and its solution, but cannot make sense of it, so I really appreciate your advice.

Question:

You have a file consisting of characters. The characters in the file can be read sequentially, but the length of the file is unknown. How do you pick a character so that every character in the file has equal probability of being chosen?

Solution: If there is a second character, we keep the first character with probability $1/2$ and replace the pick with the second character with probability $1/2$. If there is a third character, we keep the pick (from the first two characters) with probability $2/3$ and replace the pick with the third character with probability $1/3$. **Here is my doubt: what is the meaning of "we keep the pick (from the first two characters) with probability $2/3$ and replace the pick with the third character with probability $1/3$"?**, how can we make sure "we keep the pick (from the first two characters) with probability $2/3$"?

Comment: I don't understand what it is that you don't understand about the proposed process.  Which is your specific difficulty?  In understanding what it means to "keep the pick", in understanding what it means to do so with probability $\frac{2}{3}$ (*or more generally with probability $\frac{n-1}{n}$*), or something else entirely?

Comment: I'll try to rephrase it some... so, we have a file... and we are allowed to read the characters in the file but are allowed to do so only once and are not allowed to revisit old characters... think like a magnetic tape disk drive... at the start we don't know how many characters there are, so we don't know when we are allowed to end until we see that we are *at* the end.  So, we proceed one character at a time.  We make many different random number choices on whether to have our current "selected" character remain selected or be replaced by a new character... all to have equal chance at end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They mean, "Choose the first character.  If you encounter a different character, with probability $1/2$ keep the character you've already chosen, and with probability $1/2$, switch to the new character.  If a third character is encountered, switch to it with probability $1/3$, and don't switch with probability $2/3$.

It should be easy for you to see that if there are $3$ distinct characters, each has a $1/3$ chance of being chosen.  The same algorithm works with any finite number of characters: when the $k$ new character is encountered, switch with probability $1/k$.